# System.MissingMethodException: Error while deserialization of json array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, deserialization

I am getting error while deserializing jsonString.

Error is `Type 'oodleListingsUser' is not supported for deserialization of an array.`

My code of deserialization is

```
    string jsonString = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=region_value&category=category_value&format=json");

    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    jsonOodleApi p = ser.Deserialize<jsonOodleApi>(jsonString);
```

My class defination of jsonOodleApi is

```
public class jsonOodleApi
{
    public oodleCurrent current;
    public oodleListings[] listings;
    public oodleMeta meta;

    public string state { get; set; }

}
```

Defination of **oodleCurrent**  and **oodleMeta** I am not giving because its perfect !

Defination of **oodleListings** is

```
public class oodleListings
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

    public oodleListingsUser user;

    // I have skipped some of fields because it have no issue at all.

}
```

Defination of **oodleListingsUser** is

```
public class oodleListingsUser
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string photo { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is my **jsonString** sometimes returns only one value of user (type of *oodleListingsUser*), and sometimes it returns array of user, and sometimes it returns null of user !

When it returns only one user, it runs perfectly fine ! No issue.

But when it returns array of user, *bloom !* error occurs **`Type 'oodleListingsUser' is not supported for deserialization of an array.`**

Even I have tried  `public oodleListingsUser[] user` But it gives error as

```
No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'oodleListingsUser[]'
```

for the value which returns only one user !

Now what should i do to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried `public oodleListingsUser[] user;` ?

Comment: @L.B Yes ! and It runs perfectly if jsonString returns array of user !
But if jsonString returns one user it will give `No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'oodleListingsUser[]'` error

Comment: And Even I have parameter less constructor in my class code ! Still it gives error !

Comment: Try: `public oodleListings[] listings = new oodleListings[0];` Or make it a `List<oodleListings>` perhaps.

Comment: @NoOne: I'll make an answer :) Glad it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
public oodleListings[] listings = new oodleListings[0];
```

Or make it a `List<oodleListings>` perhaps.

Comment: I have tried List<oodleListings> and its working completely fine ! Thank you @leppie