# Why should I take List<> instead of array in JSON deserialization ?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, deserialization

First of all let me tell you one thing that I am posting this question is just for eagerness and to increase my knowledge. Hope you can clear my doubts !

Now lets come to the point

I got this question from my previous [question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9173811/1162201)

Actually the problem is if I use

```
List<oodleListings> listings;
```

instead of

```
oodleListings[] listings;
```

It works fine !! I can deserialize my json string easily.

Now the problem is why array is not supported while deserializing json ?

**What is the actual reason to use `List` instead of `array` ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is not related with `Array`s or `Lists`.
See the example classes below

```
public class TestClassList
{
    public List<User> users;
}

public class TestClassArray
{
    public User[] users;
}

public class User
{
    public string user;
}
```

and assume your input string is 
`string json1 = "{ users:[{user:'11'},{user:'22'}] }";`

```
var obj1= ser.Deserialize<TestClassList>(json1);
var obj2 = ser.Deserialize<TestClassArray>(json1);
```

both deserializations will work..

But if you try to deserialize this string `string json2 = "{ users:{user:'11'} }";`

```
var obj3 = ser.Deserialize<TestClassList>(json2);
var obj4 = ser.Deserialize<TestClassArray>(json2);   //<--ERROR
```

you will get error in the second line (Althoug first line doesn't give an error, it doesn't return a valid object either).

As a result: The second json string does not contain an array of users, this is why you get `No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'User[]'`.

Comment: What is `ser` in this context?

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` does not have a fixed length, so you are free to Add items to that object, without knowing its size.  List is definitely the more flexible/functional class, but as a side-effect, it has a larger memory footprint.

Also, an object of type `List<oodleListing>` will have a method `AddRange` method that takes a parameter of `oodleListing[]` so you could always deserialize and then add to your generic class.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with `Array` or `List`. I just tried your code and it works without any issue for both `Array` and `List`.

In your previous question you didn't give the JSON serialized string, other wise it would have been solved there it self. You can check [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1713640.aspx/1?Type%20System%20String%20is%20not%20supported%20for%20deserialization%20of%20an%20array%20) post from ASP.Net.

Comment: I accept ! I have not provided JSON serialized string but I have given link ! That particular link returns json data !

Comment: http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=chicago&category=vehicle&format=json Try this ! this will return value but different different categories returns diff values ! and it will be accessed by key! N due to company privacy I cant give Key ! Sorry ! But you can go further through http://developer.oodle.com