# Deserialization of a json string returns null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, javascriptserializer

### This is the JSON string -

#### "{\"body\":[\"VAL1\",\"VAL2\"],\"head\":{\"result\":true,\"time\":3.859}}"

### These are my classes -

```
[Serializable]
public class ResponseHead
{               
    public bool result {get; set;}              
    public float time {get; set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class ResponseBody
{        
    public string[] body {get; set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class ResponseObj
{        
    public ResponseBody body {get; set;}
    public ResponseHead head { get; set; }
}
```

### And the code -

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
ResponseObj response_obj = new ResponseObj();

ResponseHead rhead = new ResponseHead();
rhead = serializer.Deserialize<ResponseHead>(responseText); //not working
```

The resultant ResponseHead object has values:

```
result: false 
time: 0.0
```

It is not able to map the values correctly, but i'm not sure why. The ResponseBody values are coming in correctly.

Please help!

Comment: if you put the values inside a string in your json you will see them

Comment: did the [Serializable] work on your previus question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253436/javascriptserializer-error-responsebody-is-not-supported-for-deserialization/10256768#10256768

Comment: nope, I've added the answer that worked there. It was just a change of type. Thanks for the answer though, it may have saved me from future errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to read `ResponseObj` (which is top level object in your JSON), but coded for `ResponseHead`. Following should work:

```
var wholeObject = serializer.Deserialize<ResponseObj>(responseText);
rhead = wholeObject.head;
```

Comment: This gives me an error saying - Deserialization of an array not supported, since the ResponseBody is an array. Hence, I am trying to get the values separately. It does work if I remove the ResponseBody from ResponseObj and only keep ResponseHead and then get the value for the object as a whole. However, getting the value for ResponseHead separately isn't working.

Comment: Just change ResponseBody to an array of sting. If you cant change the json object.

Comment: If you can't get built in serializers (DataContractJsonSerializer  and JavaScriptSerializer) to work with your JSON consider [JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) which provides much more options.

Comment: @TimBJames: I considered using JSON.NET, which gave me a more descriptive error, that made me realize that the issue was to not wrap the string[] into the ResponseBody object. I got rid of that object and directly made my ResponseObject have a string[] as the body. Just came back to SO and read Tims reply asking me to do just that! After this, using JavaScriptSerializer worked as well.